# How to add to a mongo object and return it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a mongoose query that gets a bunch of venues and does a google query to get the distance to those venues and add that distance to each venue object before returning them. 
Heres the relevant code (coffeescript):

```
Venue.find
  .then (dbResponse) ->
    venues = dbResponse
    googleParam = ''
    console.log venues
    venues.forEach (venue) ->
      googleParam += venue.streetAddress + '+' + venue.city + '+' + venue.state + '|'
    request
      url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Times+Sq+New+York+NY&destinations=" + googleParam + "&key=" + process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
      json: true
    .then (response) ->
      venues = _.map venues, (venue, index) ->
        console.log index
        venue.distance = response.rows[0].elements[index].distance.text
        console.log venue.distance
        venue

      res.json venues
```

When I console.log venue.distance I get the correct values but the response still comes back with no distances, just the old venue objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to call `.lean()` on my query to make the response a plain js object.